# Include Omnichannel Routing Configurations in Change Set?

Tags: change-set, omnichannel

I am trying to build a change-set to move from a Developer environment to a QA environment. The problem I am seeing is that there does not seem to be any way to include the Routing Configurations in a Change Set?

I was trying to avoid a manual step.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thank you for the edit I lost apparently all ability to spell today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that seems not to be possible.

I was just trying to do the same and asked one of our gurus who told me to just replicate the steps in production... only thing I was able to get into change set was the permission set giving users access to availability statuses.

Answer (score 2):

You can migrate these with a workaround using data loader.

Export all (or filtered) records of the Routing Configuration (QueueRoutingConfig) object from the source org(make sure you select the "Show all Salesofrce records checkbox") and Import the records in the target org accordingly.

This also applies for Skills (if you use skill based routing in Omni-Channel)

Comment: Please **[edit]** this post to include more detail. As written, it does not contain sufficient detail.

Comment: That's just one of the many objects/configs involved in omni-channel. Service Channel itself has many related objects. Doing all these (data export and import of 8+? objects) through data loader is time consuming, which might be same as manually redoing in other orgs. The idea (which I posted) needs some love so we can deploy the omni-channel - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LhGwAAK. Upvote so Salesforce brings this feature/ fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Upvote an idea in salesforce for this need in order to get the proper attention from the SF developers team:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LhGwAAK